# Error on ADF Release pipeline - The aggregated deployment error is too large

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

I am getting the above error on my ADF release pipeline. when running :-

[image: error details]

I cant find any further helpful information in the logs. The previous steps seems to have succeeded normally as far as I can tell. Could this error be related to the number of pipelines - we have 111 pipelines and 220 datasets in this data factory. What steps do I need to take to resolve this error? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Paul, Could you deploy the ARM template via Azure Portal? Then we could see the detail error info in the Azure Portal, we could refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/quickstart-create-templates-use-the-portal)

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT, Thanks for your response, I am happy to manually deploy,  is there a clearer procedure than the link you provided? The link seems to be for simpler objects than a data factory with hundreds of pipelines and datasets and numerous json files.

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT I have now managed to manually deploy and to get the release pipeline working,  which exposed a large number or errors - these have now been addressed mostly the result of a failed SQL Server linked service and a permissions problem. The ARM template deployment task was not set to Resource mode and thus no errors no info was logged to the Resource group. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I have now managed to manually deploy and to get the release pipeline working, which exposed a large number of errors - these have now been addressed, mostly the result of a failed SQL Server linked service and a permissions problem. The ARM template deployment task was not set to Resource mode and thus no errors or info were logged to the Resource group.

Comment: Hi @Paul, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue,

Reason was, there were couple of linked services in my master branch having "invalid reference" error, and these were not present in LIVE mode of Data factory.

To Resolve this issue :
I had to update the connection string/password for these linked services and then I saved and published.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31299495)